# Passing member method of derived class as base class method pointer

Tags: c++, oop, callback, polymorphism, pointer-to-member

Can I pass the method as a pointer to some function that accepts the base class method pointer?
Like here, function `tryit` accepts two parameters with class `Object`. There should be polymorphism, but the compiler throws an error.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Object {
};


class Derived : public Object
{
private:
    
public:
    void printit() {
        cout << "Ok" << endl;
    }
};




void tryit(Object* obj, void (Object::*fn)()  ) {
    (obj->*fn)();
}


int main() {
    Derived d;
    tryit(&d, &Derived::printit);
}
```

Compiler says this:

```
main.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cc:31:15: error: cannot convert ‘void (Derived::*)()’ to ‘void (Object::*)()’
   31 |     tryit(&d, &Derived::printit);
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |               |
      |               void (Derived::*)()
main.cc:24:25: note:   initializing argument 2 of ‘void tryit(Object*, void (Object::*)())’
   24 | void tryit(Object* obj, void (Object::*fn)()  ) {
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I don't want to use virtual methods in `Object` class, because I want to be able to call function with various names.

This works:

```
typedef void (Object::*memfn)();
tryit(&d, (memfn) &Derived::printit);
```

But why this is not converted implicitly, why do I need to cast it manually?

Comment: The reason that it’s not converted implicitly is that a member function of a derived class is not necessarily a member function of the base class. If it’s not, in fact, a member of the base class, calling it through that pointer produces undefined behavior.

Comment: @PeteBecker - It is not UB. The standard refers to the dynamic type of the object for membership.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica — it’s not about the type of tobject; it’s about the type of the PMF. You have to cast it back to its original type to use it.

Comment: @PeteBecker - Both passages I linked under Sergey's answer say the opposite.

Comment: Um, “seq uenced before” doesn’t mean “valid regardless of any other factors”. It’s the same issue as casting an ordinary function pointer to a different type of function pointer. You’re allowed to do it, but you have to convert it back to its original type in order to call it.

Comment: @PeteBecker - What does sequencing have to do with it? The cast expression still produces something that points at a member of `Derived`, says so black on green. Using that pointer-to-member on something that is of dynamic type `Derived` obtains that member, says as much just before the irrelevant "sequencing" you seem intent to patronize me with.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica -- the only **requirement** in that first link is that if certain conditions are met, E1 is sequenced before E2. You're absolutely right that that's irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, polymorphism doesn't work this way. Member-pointers of derived classes are not implicitly convertible to member-pointers of parent classes. Only pointers (and references) to derived class objects are implicitly convertible to pointers to parent class objects.

You can cast your pointer, and make compiler happy:

```
int main() {
    Derived d;
    tryit(&d, static_cast<void (Object::*)()>(&Derived::printit));
}
```

Thanks to @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica for digging, there seems to be an explicit blessing in Standard:

https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.static.cast#12

Comment: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.mptr.oper#4 and https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.static.cast#12

Comment: Thanks @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica!

Answer (score 0):

Using `virtual` is the legal and safe way to handle this for polymorphic types. Your claim that you don't want to use `virtual` because you "*want to be able to call function with various names*" makes no sense.

But, if you really don't want to use `virtual` then consider making `tryit()` a template function instead, eg:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void tryit(T* obj, void (T::*fn)() ) {
    (obj->*fn)();
}

int main() {
    Derived d;
    tryit(&d, &Derived::printit);
}
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
template<typename Callable>
void tryit(Callable fn) {
    fn();
}

int main() {
    Derived d;
    tryit([&](){ d.printit(); });
}
```

Or, you can use `std::function` without a template, eg:

```cpp
void tryit(std::function<void()> fn) {
    fn(); 
}

int main() {
    Derived d;
    tryit([&](){ d.printit(); });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> But why this is not converted implicitly, why do I need to cast it manually?

Because it's one of those conversions where you *have* to tell the compiler you posses extra knowledge that guarantees it's safe. Take object pointers for instance:

```
struct A { int x; };
struct B : A { char c; };

A *pa = new B();
auto pb = static_cast<B*>(pa);
```

Converting a `B*` to an `A*` is implicit. It's an unambiguous base class. The compiler *knows* there is an `A` object in that `B` and can just go ahead with it. But the converse is not true, you must cast it (employing your extra knowledge) to let it know that that `A*` is really pointing at a `B*`.

Pointers to members are the same in a way.

```
int B::* pmb = &A::x;
auto pma = static_cast<char A::*>(&B::c);
pa->*pma = 'c';
```

Obtaining a pointer to a member of `B` from a pointer to a member of `A` is an implicit conversion. The same knowledge about `B` containing an `A` (and therefore the member `x`) is available to the compiler. But it cannot assume the converse willy-nilly. What if the object pointer `pa` is not really pointing at a `B`? Accessing that "member of B" would be disastrous then.

By the same reasoning as before, you need a cast to let the compiler know you have extra knowledge about the actual derived object type.